# How to create cylinder with varying radius at different height

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

My goal is to create a imperfect cylinder with a script, where some randomness is added to the radius of the cylinder at certain intervals. I am very new to blender unfortunately, and am lost at the approach to take.

I would imagine I would need to generate circle of vertices, connect them with edges, duplicate and extrude, move points and repeat. However, I don't have the faintest idea of the commends I would need for each step, and would appreciate any help/hints.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this with a script, rather than say a cylinder with a displacement modifier based on a noise texture? If you’re just doing this to learn scripting then of course that makes sense, but otherwise a script seems overkill for this task.

Comment: It's part of an attempt to generate a synthetic dataset, something that would be repeated thousands of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bmesh script.**

[image]

Here is but one of may ways could approach this.

**Rib n Bridge**

- Make `growth_segments` cirlcles all with `segments` segments.  Each
  has a radius in range `(min_radius, max_radius)` and the the next is
  in the range of  `(min_growth, max_growth)` above.
- A translation matrix, using the accumulative height is used to place
  each successive circle.
- Each circle is added with `bmesh`'s create circle primitive. On each
  iteration a "rib" is the last added `segments` edges of the bmesh.
- Skinned by bridging each rib with its next.
- Finally the first and last ribs are ngon filled with the
  `contextual_create` operator, somewhat akin to `bmesh`'s <kbd>F</kbd>
  "fill" key.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context # for testing
import bmesh
from random import uniform
from mathutils import Matrix

segments = 16
min_radius = 0.5
max_radius = 2.0

growth_segments = 10
min_growth = 1.0
max_growth = 2.0


bm = bmesh.new()

h = 0
ribs = []     
# make the circles 
for i in range(growth_segments):
    bmesh.ops.create_circle(
            bm,
            segments=segments,
            radius=uniform(min_radius, max_radius),
            matrix=Matrix.Translation((0, 0, h)),
            )  
    h += uniform(min_growth, max_growth) 
    ribs.append(bm.edges[-segments:])

# bridge the loops
for rib, ribnext in zip(ribs, ribs[1:]):
    bmesh.ops.bridge_loops(
            bm,
            edges=rib + ribnext,
            ) 
            
# fill the ends

bmesh.ops.contextual_create(
        bm,
        geom=ribs[0] + ribs[-1],
        )       
        
# Create object load mesh 
me = bpy.data.meshes.new("RandomCyl")
bm.to_mesh(me)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("RandomCyl", me)
context.collection.objects.link(ob)
# make selected and active
ob.select_set(True)
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

**Matrices**

Have used a matrix in the create circle operator to translate to the height

[image]

Here I've extended this a bit further to give a panel beaten effect, each rib is now a random ellipse using above min max for two radii, and also rotated randomly 0 to 45 degrees in Z.

A diagonal matrix is a quick way to produce a scale matrix.

```
Sx = Matrix.Scale(4, 3, 'X')
```

is equiv of

```
S = Matrix.Diagonal((4, 1, 1))
```

Each circle is transformed by `R @ T @ S` (rotation, translation, scale)

```
    bmesh.ops.create_circle(
            bm,
            segments=segments,
            radius=1,
            matrix=(
                Matrix.Rotation(uniform(0, 0.7854), 4, 'Z') @
                Matrix.Translation((0, 0, h)) @
                Matrix.Diagonal(
                    (
                    uniform(min_radius, max_radius),
                    uniform(min_radius, max_radius),
                    1, 
                    )
                ).to_4x4() # since tanslation mat is 4x4
                ),
            )
```

Cannot emphasize enough, the better we become at using linear algebra (vectors and matrices) the "easier" it will be to use API methods. Is also generally faster and IMO cleaner.

**Spin Profile**

Another way would be to make  profile edges on XZ plane and spin it around z axis to make a solid of revolution.

[image]
*Equivalent of making profile shown on left, and creating mesh by spinning it with the screw modifier (default settings)*

```
import bpy
from bpy import context # for testing
import bmesh
from random import uniform
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians

segments = 16
min_radius = 0.5
max_radius = 2.0

growth_segments = 10
min_growth = 1.0
max_growth = 2.0


bm = bmesh.new()

h = 0
verts = [bm.verts.new()]

for h in range(growth_segments):
    radius = uniform(min_radius, max_radius)
    verts.append(
            bm.verts.new((radius, 0, h))
            )
    h += uniform(min_growth, max_growth)
    
verts.append(bm.verts.new((0, 0, verts[-1].co.z)))

for edge in zip(verts, verts[1:]):
    bm.edges.new(edge)
    
# spin the sucker

bmesh.ops.spin(
        bm,
        geom=bm.edges[:],
        axis=(0, 0, 1), # z axis
        angle=radians(360), # 2pi one rev
        steps=segments,
        )
```