# Blender 2.93 API primitive_cube_add change

Tags: python, scripting

This script is able to run properly in 2.92, but 2.93 doesn't seem to output the same results for the created cube.

```
import bpy
x= 10
y= 10
z= 10
dx= 10
dy= 10
dz= 10
scale = 1
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=((x+dx/2)*scale,(y+dy/2)*scale,(z+dz/2)*scale), scale=(dx*scale,dy*scale,dz*scale))
```

In 2.93, the cube is twice as large. (If I put size=1 , I get the same cube as the 2.92 with size=2)

I don't see any related changes in the Blender changelog, does this mean this is to be a permanent change to the API, or is it just a bug, or I am doing something bad?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212886/strange-size-when-creating-a-cube-using-bpy-ops-mesh-primitive-cube-add

Comment: I ran the script both in 2.92. and 2.93, both gave the exact same mesh results in global, dimension, and scale. Did you perhaps change the Scene "Unit" type in one of your Blender versions.

Comment: Possible related: https://developer.blender.org/T86347