# Is it possible to create a shortcut button for a cube and sphere with custom dimensions?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

[image]

For example:

I want to be able to just click a button and able to have the same size cube or sphere every time.
I'm gonna be making hundreds of cubes and spheres all the same size but I don't want to keep having re-size them every time I create them.

I want the  spheres to always be 10m and the Cubes to be 15 x15x20mm
Is this possible?

Thank so you for time in advance weather you can help or not

---

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "WIRES  &  PIPES"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    #bl_category = "Shortcuts"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        op = row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="Plug", icon="MESH_CUBE")
        op.size = 0.5
        op.scale = (1, 2, 3)

        op = row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", text="Ground", icon="MESH_UVSPHERE")
        op.radius = 0.1

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: can you tell us a bit more why you need hundreds of cubes? do you move them all by hand? or why do you need that much?

Comment: just e.g. you could just use CTRL-D to duplicate an object - which is IMHO faster than tapping a button....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add the operator properties to the layout.**

Add a primitive using the UI, and take note of the chosen parameters.  Can then add to draw method of TOOL panel

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column()
        op = col.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
        op.scale = (1, 2, 3)
        op.size = 1
```

will add an add cube operator button  than when pressed adds a  dimension (0.5, 1.0, 1.5) blender unit cube to the scene.

Related:

- [How to pass multiple operator properties via UI layout?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-pass-multiple-operator-properties-via-ui-layout)
- [Strange size when creating a cube using bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212886/strange-size-when-creating-a-cube-using-bpy-ops-mesh-primitive-cube-add)

To see any errors or warnings: [Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

Comment: Hello BatFINGER.....
Where can I add the custom size here? I think I am doing something wrong, I'm super new at this               

row = layout.row()

row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", text="Plug", icon="MESH_CUBE")
    
row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", text="Ground", icon="MESH_UVSPHERE")

Comment: As in answer. `op = row.operator(...)` then `op.size = 0.2`

Comment: I'm still screwing it up somehow :(

Comment: Edit your draw method into question.

Comment: batFINGER, I tired the script that you helped me with, but my cubes still didn't change dimension. I feel really stupid doing this lol especially since I never written anything before. I looked at the other suggestions but they just confused me even more :P

Comment: @DanielRahmani going by image in question you are using an earlier version of blender.   Things change slightly over time.  Go to the python console in blender  and type in `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(` and hit "Ctrl-Space" together for it to auto complete, showing the options. IIRC it could be the case that `radius` is used instead of `size`     If this is the case there will be an error message in system console,  added  link above re seeing errors in system console.